# react-admin how to reduce the line spacing of the list

Tags: react-admin

the react-admin default  line spacing is too large.how to change it.

I did not find any way to custom the table style .if have a way to change the global of list line spacing ?

I have try to custom theme ,but did not work

```
const myTheme = createMuiTheme({
 overrides: {
   MuiTableRow: {
     root: {
       height: 20,
     },
   },
 },
});
```

following is my component which want to take effect.

```
    <List {...props} >
      <Datagrid rowClick="show" rowStyle={rowStyle}>
        <TextField source="batch" />
        <TextField source="onHandQty" label="On hand" />
        <TextField source="availableQty" label="Available" />
        <TextField source="reservedQty" label="Reserved" />
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
```

Comment: sorry，change the height of MuiTableRow will be effect .unless, the field have break through.